# sprites go off-screen after Collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

When the game starts the ball will bounce off the edges perfectly using this code:

```
    if (Is_hit == true && ballFired == true )
    {
        //collision here
        ballXPos = 960 - ballimg.Width - (ballXPos - 960 + ballimg.Width);
        ballXDir = +1;

        ballYDir = -1;
    }

    if (Ballvisible == true)
    {


        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && ballFired == false)
        {
            ballFired = true;

        }
        if (ballFired == true)
        {


            ballXPos = ballXPos - (ballSpeed * ballXDir);

            ballYPos = ballYPos + (ballSpeed * ballYDir);

        }
        if (ballXPos < 0)
        {
            ballXPos = -ballXPos;
            ballXDir = -1;


        }
        if (ballXPos > 960 - ballimg.Width)
        {
            ballXPos = 960 - ballimg.Width - (ballXPos - 960 + ballimg.Width);
            ballXDir = +1;


        }
        if (ballYPos < 0)
        {
            ballYPos = +ballYPos;
            ballYDir = +1;

        }
      if (ballYPos > 700 - ballimg.Height)
      {
          Ballvisible = false;
      }


  }
  if (Ballvisible == false)
  {

      ballSpeed = 3;
      ballXDir = -1;
      ballYDir = -1;

      ballXPos = 450;
      ballYPos = 590;
      ballFired = false;
      Ballvisible = true;
  }



}
```

but once a collision has occurred  the ball will bounce off another sprite(the player paddle) successfully but then  the program seems to ignore this code and the ball will go straight off the screen.

collision code:

```
  // paddle collison detection 
            if   
   (  gameball.PositionRectangle_ball.Intersects(paddle.PositionRectangle_paddle))
            {

     collision_paddle = true; 
                gameball.CheckCollision(collision_paddle); // passes the collision bool value 
            }
```

Comment: Do you ever clear the `Is_hit` flag?

Comment: hi, thanks for that! i forgot i need to reset it, i tried reseting it outside of my collision check and it causes the game to act rather weird. how would you go about reseting it if there is no collision?

Comment: If I didn't need to check it anywhere else I would clear it in the first block of the posted code, the one with the comment  `// collision here`

Comment: thanks! that's worked perfectly. really appreciate your help. if you post it as an answer i will mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to clear the `Is_hit` flag.

If you don't need to check it anywhere else you can clear it in the first block of the posted code:

```
if (Is_hit == true && ballFired == true )
{
    //collision here
    ballXPos = 960 - ballimg.Width - (ballXPos - 960 + ballimg.Width);
    ballXDir = +1;

    ballYDir = -1;
    Is_hit = false;
}
```